# Do Until function with if loop "Object error"

Tags: vba, excel

```
Option Explicit
Sub Autoselect()

Dim Refcolor As Long
Dim RefRow As Long
Dim Refcol As Long
Dim IncRow As Long
Dim RCap As Long

Refcolor = RGB(220, 230, 241)
RefRow = Selection.Row
Refcol = 2  'Will get back to ref column later
RCap = 2000
IncRow = RefRow

Do Until IncRow = RefRow + RCap
If Cells(IncRow, "B").Interior.Color = Refcolor Then
Cells(IncRow, "B").Select
Exit Do
Else
If Cells(IncRow, "B").Value = Nothing Then
Cells(IncRow, "B").Select
Exit Do
Else
End If
IncRow = IncRow + 1
Loop
```

Trying to create a function call autoselect which will select the cell which contains the color `RGB(220,230,241)` or the cell which does not contain any value on Column "B". The start of function will be from the selection.row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is coming from the following statement:

```
If Cells(IncRow, "B").Value = Nothing Then
```

`Nothing` is used for objects, not intrinsic types (strings, numbers, booleans). To test if `Value` is blank/empty, use the `IsEmpty()` function:

```
If IsEmpty(Cells(IncRow, "B").Value) Then
```